# Issue with Boost libraries cross compilation

Tags: linux, boost, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile Boost, but I ended up with the following errors.

I have done the following steps:

1. Unzipped boost_1_68_0.tar.bz2
2. Executed Bootstrap
3. Edited user-config.jam using

   ```
   gcc:arm:arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-g++
   ```
4. Executed `./b2 --prefix=install toolset=gcc-arm --user-config=./user-config.jam`
5. also exceuted `./bjam --prefix=install toolset=gcc-arm --user-config=./user-config.jam`

But I ended up with the following error:

```
    "arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-g++"   -fPIC -pthread -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall  -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/wave/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/cpplexer/re2clex/aq.o" "libs/wave/src/cpplexer/re2clex/aq.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/wave/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/cpplexer/re2clex/aq.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/wave/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/cpplexer/re2clex/cpp_re.o
libs/wave/src/cpplexer/re2clex/cpp_re.cpp:20:10: fatal error: ctime: No such file or directory
 #include <ctime>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

There are a lot of errors like these.

Comment: You should probably add a `--with-sysroot` (or the Bjam equivalent) to tell the toolchain where to find headers and libs.

Comment: @jww what path exactly to be added to `--with-sysroot`

Comment: I don't use Boost, so I have no idea how to use their tools. I have a lot of experience with cross-compiling. Based on your problem write-up, you are not providing a sysroot but you need to provide one, or manually pass header and lib locations. (When I performed a quick search for Boost, Bjam and sysroot I found lots of hits. Why have you not tried one?)

Comment: i'm including sysroot but still it gives the same errors, but there is one thing to say in my toolchain there is a boost 1.66 version and i'm trying to 1.68 version but i'm mentioning these paths.so,does anyone think that it might be the issue for my problem

Comment: come on guys anyone help me i'm stuck with it since a week

Comment: @jww thank you so much,the problem with sysroot only finally i'm able to pass the sysroot to the build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the sysroot. We have to pass sysroot also with the compiler:

```
gcc : arm : arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-g++ -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/opt/iotgw-sdk-prod/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi
```

Note: The blank spaces should tabs, not spaces.